# Why does it take so long to update the HttpServletResponse? (Apache Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, httpresponse

I'm running Apache Tomcat 8 on Eclipse Mars on Windows 7, and here's my piece of code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Main")
public class Main extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Main() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("");
        pw.println("");
        pw.println("");
        pw.println("<h1>Example 0</h1>");
        pw.println("");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

It starts tomcat, ok, and "Example 0" can be seen when I access localhost. BUT, if I change the string in the response to "Example 1", it takes around 10 min to change it. I'm a beginner in Servlet / Tomcat development, and I'm failing to grasp the reason why the delay occurs. Why that happens??

Comment: What do you mean _to change it_?

Comment: Your build process is capable of taking changes made to Java files (excluding changes like adding new methods / Classes) and deploying them to your server automatically. To enable this without restarts for a select set of changes, your WAR file should be deployed exploded. Is `Build automatically` checked for your project in eclipse and is the WAR exploded?

Comment: I see it now. I was running Tomcat from the workspace in Eclipse, and it was taking too long to update the changes (Build automatically was checked already). Now I'm running Tomcat's startup.bat externally and exporting the .war file of the project to the webapps folder. This way, when I press F5 on Google Chrome, it updates instantly. Interesting difference. I still don't understand exactly what happens that causes the update-delay.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I recommend you code web stuffs with Netbeans, there is no doubt Eclipse is the king, but Netbeans does web stuffs better.